# Fantasy series where in the first book a poor girl gets saved by a mage

Tags: story-identification

At first she was kind of terrified of him, but then he just gives her some money to apply for the magic academy and leaves. She had some trouble with the registration (the school is usually for rich snobs only), but in the end she does get in and becomes one of the best mages.

Then there’s something about a war (long part but can’t remember clearly) so the girl travels the world to try and resolve the war in a humane manner. The cause of the war seems to have been resource imbalance or something, and one big powerful city wanting to take over the whole world.

I think there was something about some ancient civilisation of powerful mages as well.

The female protagonist has some dalliance with a desert prince, but that relationship falls apart, and she ultimately falls in love with her mentor? Who disappeared after the final conflict and left his little secluded hut to her. she then shuts herself up in the hut until her mentor reappears and goes back to her.

Honestly I don’t even know if this is fanfiction or a jumble of different series mashed up in my brain. but if anybody has any idea please let me know! especially the part about the ending

Answer (score 8):

Some of what you describe is pretty common fantasy tropes, and some of it doesn't fit what I'm about to suggest, but as you mention that you could be mixing up different series in your head, I'm going to suggest it anyway.

Could you be recalling **Trudi Canavan's *Black Magician* series**? It starts with [*The Magician's Guild*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magicians%27_Guild) and continues in two further novels, plus a sequel trilogy and a prequel novel. (Wikipedia doesn't seem to have pages for anything except the first novel and the prequel, but you can read reviews, including spoilery ones, on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28251.The_High_Lord) to get more detail.)

Points that match:

- > in the first book a poor girl gets saved by a mage

  Sort of. Sonea is a girl from the lower classes, who unexpectedly realises she has magical potential. The Magician's Guild hunt for her, while she begins to lose control of her emerging powers and destroy her surroundings, until she is found by the kindly magician Rothen.
- > She had some trouble with the registration (the school is usually for rich snobs only), but in the end she does get in and becomes one of the best mages.

  This fits. All of the trainees in the Magician's Guild are rich snobs except for her. She has trouble especially with one bully, but her magical abilities are among the best.
- > Then there’s something about a war (long part but can’t remember clearly) so the girl travels the world to try and resolve the war in a humane manner.

  Sort of. The war with Sachaka dominates book 3, and she ends up getting exiled from the Guild (together with her [second] mentor, High Lord Akkarin) for using black magic, therefore travelling together.
- > I think there was something about some ancient civilisation of powerful mages as well.

  Yep, that'd probably be the Sachakan magicians, more powerful than the Kyralian Magicians' Guild due to their use of black magic (higher magic).
- > she ultimately falls in love with her mentor? Who disappeared after the final conflict and left his little secluded hut to her.

  Pretty much. She falls in love with her (second) mentor, High Lord Akkarin, but he dies at the end of the third book. I don't remember anything about a hut, but it's been more than a decade since I read these books.

Points that don't match:

- > At first she was kind of terrified of him, but then he just gives her some money to apply for the magic academy and leaves.

  Rothen doesn't give Sonea money and leave: he becomes her (first) mentor in the magic academy.
- > The cause of the war seems to have been resource imbalance or something, and one big powerful city wanting to take over the whole world.

  I don't remember anything about this. IIRC, the cause of the war was Sachaka wanting to get revenge for losing a previous war? And maybe being power-hungry, yeah - after the Sachakans realised that they practise the stronger kind of magic which the Kyralians don't, they feel powerful enough to invade and conquer anywhere (and they almost do manage).
- > The female protagonist has some dalliance with a desert prince, but that relationship falls apart

  She has a couple of dalliances before her relationship with Akkarin, but nobody who could be described as a "desert prince" (although one of them was a young nobleman who later found her in the desert with Akkarin).
- > she then shuts herself up in the hut until her mentor reappears and goes back to her.

  I don't think Akkarin ever reappears, even at the very end.

Answer (score 4):

This bears heavy resemblance with [Schooled in magic](http://www.chrishanger.net/Published/SIMseries/SIMindex.html) by Christopher Nuttall.

A girl from our world is pulled into a fantasy medieval world by a necromancer who intends to sacrifice her. In these series, "necromancer" just means "super-powerful dark mage who's gone mad". She is rescued by Void, a powerful magician - pretty much the most powerful magician on that world, as it later turns out, and the only one who can stand up to a necromancer in a magic duel. Void tells her he would be an awful teacher, so he sends her off to a school for magicians called Whitehall. He tells everyone that she is his daughter. She's both impressed by him, by the fact that he rescued her and basically adopted her and paid for her scholarship. She's also a bit terrified of him, because he lives in a cliché silver tower in the middle of nowhere, and employs brainwashed servants. Much later in the series when she finally gets to come back to the tower, the brainwashed servants are retconned out and silently replaced with non-brainwashed servants so that he looks less like a villain.

At first she struggles a lot, because she was not raised in that world, knows nothing about magic, and can't even read the local language. But she has knowledge from our world, which somehow helps her have insightful ideas and come up with new magic spells that will gradually make her stronger than everyone else.

She also sends some ideas from our world to a merchant who is the father of one of her friends from the school. In the first book, these ideas include the Latin alphabet, the Arabic number system, bras, and double-entry accounting. Later in the series she also tells them about the printing press, the steam engine, banks, gunpowder, democracy, feminism, hygiene, university, and a bunch of other kingdom-shattering ideas.

At the end of the first book the school is attacked by the necromancer from the first chapter. Everything seems lost, but then she gets to show off the cool new spells that she invented and becomes the first magician to have ever defeated a necromancer.

Some of the next books in the series are focused on her later years of study at the magic school, but also on her exploration of the world, which includes becoming a baroness, taming revolts, provoking revolutions, teaching nobles that famishing and raping peasants is bad, going to war against the necromancers, preventing a stockmarket crash after she reinvented economy, breaching magic castles that can't be breached, going to war against the necromancers again, visiting other magic schools, defeating the world's champion duelist in a duel, going to war against a king, defeating the necromancers once and for all, going to the past, fighting magic-eating spiders with a simple trick that no other magician had tried before, fighting herself from an alternate universe, and after all that, going on an apprenticeship with her adopted father Void.

Void is a mysterious mentor, who supposedly had a whole secret plan to fight necromancers. The secret plan is hinted at throughout the series, but he never got to reveal his plan because she becomes so powerful with all her cool new spells and inventions, that she defeated the necromancers by accident before he could finally put his plan in motion.

> The female protagonist has some dalliance with a desert prince, but that relationship falls apart, and she ultimately falls in love with her mentor?

These are the two points that don't fit:

- She never falls in love with her mentor, who remains a father figure and not a love interest;
- She falls in love with several boys throughout the series, and all of those relations fall apart after a short time, but all those boys are magicians, not desert princes. She does meet several princes, and some of them do try to court her, and she even goes to a big desert to fight a war, but none of those princes have any success with her, because they are entitled aristocrats with chauvinist medieval thinking, whereas she's a modern magician with progressive feminist ideas.

Comment: Is this Whitehall in their world, or is it the Whitehall in real-world London?

Comment: @AJM In their world. She's the only one who comes from our world. There is nothing from our world except the ideas she tells them about. I edited to make that sentence more clear.